# how to find maximum count in a linked table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

With the above code I want to find the maximum employees from a section BUT we can not find out how to take it ONLY with the specific name.

By this I mean that I want to have as a result only the name 'Development' and in its right the number 223.

I don not want the other departments or numbers.

I've tried many ways but I can't solve it.

In case the picture does not show well enough I give you the code I wrote below:

```
select dept_name, count(emp_no)
from departments 
join current_dept_emp using(dept_no)
group by dept_no;
```

Comment: Please post code here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Posting codes using an image is not appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
    dept_name,
    count(emp_no) AS empcount
FROM
    departments
JOIN current_dept_emp USING (dept_no)
GROUP BY
    dept_no
ORDER BY
    empcount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It throws an error (1064): Syntax error near '1 dept_name, count(emp_no) as emcount the from departments join current_dept_' at line 1

Comment: Sorry - didn't realize you were using MySQL (top 1 is mssql) I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SET @depName = 'Development';

SELECT 
    dept_name, COUNT(emp_no)
FROM
    departments
        JOIN
    current_dept_emp USING (dept_no)
WHERE
    dept_name LIKE @depName
GROUP BY dept_no;
```

Or by create stored procedure to get depName as input :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_dept_summary;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_dept_summary(IN depName NVARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        dept_name, COUNT(emp_no)
    FROM
        departments
            JOIN
        current_dept_emp USING (dept_no)
    WHERE
        dept_name LIKE depName
    GROUP BY dept_no;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

then you can call it like this:

```
Set @depName = 'Development';
CALL get_dept_summary(@depName);
```

If you don't know the name of department, just change where clause base on your requirements.

Comment: we suppose we do not know which is the answer.

Comment: Do you know the department name before exec query? You mentioned the department name in your question ('Development'), how do you find that?

Comment: Do you want the department with the most employees? I.e order by count of employees desc and select top 1?

Comment: Shadmehr I know it from the picture that I posted. Yes @ninjaRoche I don't understand what you mean with this "I.e order by count of employees desc and select top 1?" can you post the code?